# How can I get the addStudent method to work correctly?

Tags: javascript

I have been up all night trying to find out what I am doing wrong. I have an Object 'studentScores' and a method addStudent, I get errors and if I don't get errors it just consoles the entire function. Here is my code-

```
let studentScores = {
studentOne: {
    fName: 'Joey',
    lName: 'Hendricks',
    score: 100
},
studentTwo: {
    fName: 'Tim',
    lName: 'Izer',
    score: 98
},
studentThree: {
    fName: 'Amy',
    lName: 'Krueger',
    score: 69
},
addStudent: function(stuNum, name1, name2, stuScore){
    // this.stuNum.push({
    //  stuNum:,
    //  fName: name1,
    //  lName: name2,
    //  score: stuScore
    // });

    return this.stuNum = {fName: name1, lName: name2, score: stuScore};
}
};
```

When I do it like this-

```
console.log(studentScores.studentFour = {fName: 'Jimi', lName: 'Hendrix', score: 98});
```

It works perfectly. Can someone lead me in right direction to what I'm doing wrong? I thank you so very much.
Thank you.

Comment: So a few questions/pointers.  `this.stuNum.push()` looks to be problematic for two reasons.  1) `stuNum` is a variable.  However `this.stuNum` is going to use it as a literal property name, which i'm 99.999% sure is not your intention.  You will most likely want to use `this[stuNum]` instead to use the variable to resolve to a value.  2) `.push()` is used for arrays.  No where in your logic do you have arrays.  You only have objects.  So that is problematic.  Also if `this[stuNum]` does not exist, trying to push on it would also be a null pointer exception

Comment: Thank you very much, I will work on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If key of object is variable you should use `[]` instead of dot.

```js
let studentScores = {
  studentOne: {
    fName: 'Joey',
    lName: 'Hendricks',
    score: 100
  },
  studentTwo: {
    fName: 'Tim',
    lName: 'Izer',
    score: 98
  },
  studentThree: {
    fName: 'Amy',
    lName: 'Krueger',
    score: 69
  },
  addStudent(stuNum, name1, name2, stuScore) {
    return (this[stuNum] = {
        fName: name1,
        lName: name2,
        score: stuScore
      })
    }
  }

studentScores.addStudent('studentFour', 'Jimi', 'Hendrix', 98)
console.log(studentScores)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Manuilov, that worked for me!! Thank you very much.